# Get File Size of File to download using FTP

Tags: iphone, ftp

I am using the simpleFTPsample of apple. I want to display a progress bar of the file being downloaded. I understand it needs to be done in:


 `- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode`


under the case:


  `case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:`

how do i retrive the file size from the NSInputStream?

I have also tried:

i have set:


 `[self.networkStream setProperty:@"YES" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPFetchResourceInfo];`


and then:


 `NSLog(@"size: %@",[self.networkStream propertyForKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPResourceSize]);`


but the result is null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set kCFStreamPropertyFTPFetchResourceInfo to true. That way the CFFTPStream will send a `STAT` command to the FTP server to get file info, including the total size.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. i have change the question to include your answer. did i it wrong?

Comment: Maybe instead of @"YES" you will need [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]. Also, the server will have to support this. An way to debug this is to run tcpdump and look at what the CFStream is actually sending to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To get the file size you just need:

```
case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
      fileSize = [[self.networkStream propertyForKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPResourceSize] integerValue];}
```

By the way do you know how to get the modification date of the file in the ftp server??

Comment: This only works if you have the following after you open the stream:

    [self.networkStream setProperty: kCFBooleanTrue forKey: kCFStreamPropertyFTPFetchResourceInfo];

Otherwise you will only get zero.

Comment: FYI, size is the only thing that the documentation says is retrievable this way.